# Variation on knapsack - minimum total cost with exact weight

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

There are types of items (N types), each have weight wi and cost ci. There are an infinite number of each. The problem is to make a knapsack with EXACT (W) weight and minimum total cost of items. I know I should use dynamic in this case, but it's not a usual knapsack problem and I can't find the relation. I also found some similar questions, but I haven`t understood theese solutions. Here are the links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949705/variation-on-knapsack-minimum-total-value-exceeding-w?rq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457143/knapsack-with-minimum-cost/15457546?noredirect=1#comment21873666_15457546).
How to use DP to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let f[i] means, to get weight i, the minimum cost. g[i] means whether it is possible to combine exactly weight i;

```
f[0]=0;g[0]=true;
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<W;j++)
        if (g[j]) {
            g[j+w[i]]=true;
            if (f[j+w[i]]==0||f[j+w[i]]>f[j]+c[i])
                f[j+w[i]]=f[j]+c[i];
        }

if (g[W]) return f[W];
else return 0;//impossible
```

Comment: Does this algorithm really take the unbounded nature into account? (That there's an infinite number of each type available). I can't quite see how it does?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to find the minimum cost it can take you to accomplish a weight of `W` and that `c_i > 0` and `w_i > 0` then we can define `min_cost(i, W)` as the minimum cost that can be achieved using only items from `i` to `N` whose weight is `W`

- The base case happens when we only have one item, thus when `i=N`. In that case the solution is:

  `min_cost(N, 0) = 0` because if we do not use item `N` then we already have a weight equal to 0

  `min_cost(N, W) = c_i * W / w_i` if `W` is a multiple of `w_i` i.e `W mod w_i = 0`

  `min_cost(N, W) = Infinity` otherwise since we cannot achieve a weight of exactly `W` with only the last item.
- The recurrent relation can now be stated as:

  `min_cost(i, W) = min(c_i * k + min_cost(i+1, W - k * w_i))` for `k=0` until `W - k*w_i < 0`

The recurrent relation states that we will use item `i` as many times as possible while we have not made a weight bigger than `W`.

You can then implement this methodology with a recursive algorithm using [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and storing as you see fit the actual solutions (the `k`s in the recurrence).

**Edit** Upon a suggestion a speedup can be achieved if we notice that there are two cases that influence `min_cost(i, W)`. Such cases are first when do not need to use the ith item at all i.e. `min_cost(i+1, W)` and when we are going to use the ith item at least once, which is the same as `min_cost(i, W - w_i)` since we might use item `i` more than one time. This changes our recurrence to the following:

```
min_cost(i, 0) = 0         // We already reached our goal
min_cost(i, W) = Infinity  // if (W < 0 or i > N) then we can't get to W

min_cost(i, W) = min(min_cost(i+1, W), min_cost(i, W - w_i) + c_i)
```

Comment: Here's a speedup: if for a given i you calculate weights in increasing order, then to calculate `min_cost(i, W)` you only ever need to try adding either 0 instances of item i to the optimal solution for items i+1 .. N, or 1 instance of item i to the optimal solution *for items i .. N* (which you've already calculated because it has lower weight): `min_cost(i, W) = min(min_cost(i+1, W), min_cost(i, W-w_i) + c_i)`. In the worst case where all weights are 1, this kills a factor of W.

Comment: I added that speedup as an edit to the answer. Good speedup and way simpler, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! P.S. If you write e.g. "@j_random_hacker" somewhere in a comment, it will notify that person.  I only noticed your comment because I came back out of vanity :-P

Comment: @GustavoTorres, Any chance you have a look at this - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415617? Thank You.